# Responsive css behaving strangely

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Don't even know where to begin. My guess is that this happened when i tried to syle bootstraps col-xs to a different width. Took away that styling. Didn't help. Canceled a few other latest changes. It stays the same. I know that's a lot to ask to look for something in a source, but i don't have any idea where to look.

For some reason. the site gets styled for small screen.

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr6/acupuncture/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.col-xs-12 {
width: 300px;
}
```

and

```
.entry-content p {
min-width: 300px;
}
```

find this `style` and remove it, its conflicting with the responsive style.

Comment: just remove the both style above and your site is good to go, the second one is when your at the `< 990` screen size.

Comment: Now, here is another lesson. If you feel like you are falling asleep- you stop everything and go to sleep. I was uploading styles file into a folder where it was not supposed to go... lol thanks!

Comment: Its cool, everyone makes mistakes. :) btw tick th answer if its what your looking for. xD

Answer (score 0):

the main div there is a `<div class="row">`. I assume you need that div inside a `<div class="container">`. Look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container